# Left joining two reference tables to get the proper value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table with client data, and I must join it with two reference tables in order to get the desired text value. So someone somehow did not include all the data in one reference table, so for some of the data I need to get the value from another table.

First table with Data

```
ID         ClientID            CompanyID
1          199                 80
2          187                 91
3          85                  1001
4          83                  1145
```

Company ID as can be seen varies from 80 - 1200

The problem is, only values with > 1000 are stored in the reference table with companies, so

```
tblCompanies

CompanyID         CompanyName
1001              Microsoft
1002              Apple
1145              HP
```

the rest of Company names are stored in another table

```
tblReference

ID        FldName       Label
80        Company       Adobe
81        Company       Amazon
91        Company       Pixel
```

tblReference has much other data but for the most part it only reference ID's from 80 - 90, and all other CompanyID's are from tblCompanies....

How would I be able to join this two tables? without getting duplicate records. I tried UNION and UNIOAN ALL but it didn't work out

Answer (score 5):

First union your `tblcompanies` and `tblReferences` tables together, then join:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.clientid, t1.CompanyID, t2.CompanyName
FROM firstTable as t1
    INNER JOIN 
        (
             SELECT companyID, companyName FROM tblCompanies
             UNION ALL
             SELECT id, label FROM tblReference WHERE fldname = 'Company'
        ) t2 ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyId
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just join both of them since, according to your example, the CompanyID wouldn't be in both tables? Also, UNION ALL keeps duplicates, UNION doesn't.

```
select
    d.id
    ,d.ClientID
    ,d.CompanyID
    ,Company = coalesce(c.CompanyName,r.Label)
from    
    Data d
    left join
       tblCompanies c on
       c.CompanyID = d.CompanyID
    left join
       tblReference r on
       r.id = t.CompanyID
       and r.FldName = 'Company'
where
   coalesce(c.CompanyName,r.Label) is not null --optional
```

Comment: no worries @BobSki, i definitly didn't see the need for a union or cte like the other answers which would make it slower :)

Comment: yeah this is simpler i was actully trying to do it with union before posting the question but i wasn't getting the right data.